# Weighting events in particle physics

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics

Could someone elaborate the concept of the weighing events in Particle physics data? When do we exactly weigh the events? If we have both MC and real data, which dataset should be re weighted?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you link to one or two examples of "weighting" in the sense that you have in mind? It's a complicated topic and different people may use the term to mean slightly different things.

Comment: @rob I had seen a formula $\Sigma n_i w_i = \sigma L$ somewhere and was thus wondering as to when we use it? Having $w_i = 1$ will give us unweighted sample. So, my question is to when do we use weights and if I want to compare MC with data, do I have to do weighing? If so, in which case?

Comment: *"if I want to compare MC with data, do I have to do weighing? If so, in which case?"* That depends entirely on the MC in question, and only the documentation (if you are lucky or code if you are not) of the program can answer that for you. I've even used code where the answer was "yes" in general, but "no" for one class of running conditions.

Comment: @dmckee Could you please give any one example where you weighted the MC and what was the reason for weighing?

Comment: I don't think you really believed what I wrote. You must read the documentation for the simulation. A simulation is a computer program. It does what the programmer told it to do. That might or might not require the user to weight events, but no one can answer the question for you without know what simulation is involved, and the usual place to find this information is in the documentation.